# Issue in test-environment install

Tags: solidity, testing, truffle-test, unittesting, npm

I tried to install test-environment, it throws the error. Please advice on how to solve this.

```
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git



PS E:\Blockchain> npm i @openzeppelin/test-environment
npm WARN deprecated ganache-core@2.13.2: ganache-core is now ganache; visit https://trfl.io/g7 for details
npm WARN deprecated cids@0.7.5: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@1.0.4: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated core-js@2.6.12: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
npm WARN deprecated debug@3.2.6: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-tx@1.3.7: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/tx. Please update.
npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-block@1.7.1: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/block. Please update.
npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-vm@2.6.0: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/vm. Please update.
npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-block@2.2.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/block. Please update.
npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-tx@2.1.2: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/tx. Please update.
npm WARN deprecated eth-sig-util@3.0.0: Deprecated in favor of '@metamask/eth-sig-util'
npm WARN deprecated ethashjs@0.0.8: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/ethash. Please update.
npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-account@3.0.0: Please use Util.Account class found on package ethereumjs-util@^7.0.6 https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-util/releases/tag/v7.0.6
npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-blockchain@4.0.4: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/blockchain. Please update.
npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-common@1.5.0: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/common. Please update.
npm WARN deprecated ethereumjs-vm@4.2.0: New package name format for new versions: @ethereumjs/vm. Please update.
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp-promise@5.0.1: This package is broken and no longer maintained. 'mkdirp' itself supports promises now, please switch to that.
npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.6.1: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multicodec@0.5.7: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated multibase@0.7.0: This module has been superseded by the multiformats module
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated safe-event-emitter@1.0.1: Renamed to @metamask/safe-event-emitter
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.3.2: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated eth-sig-util@1.4.2: Deprecated in favor of '@metamask/eth-sig-util'
npm WARN deprecated @ensdomains/ens@0.4.5: Please use @ensdomains/ens-contracts
npm WARN deprecated @ensdomains/resolver@0.2.4: Please use @ensdomains/ens-contracts
npm WARN deprecated testrpc@0.0.1: testrpc has been renamed to ganache-cli, please use this package from now on.
npm WARN deprecated uuid@2.0.1: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn git
npm ERR! path git
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent Error while executing:
npm ERR! enoent undefined ls-remote -h -t https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent
npm ERR! enoent spawn git ENOENT
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Comment: What command did you run? The github repo it's trying to download from is deprecated and says to use https://docs.ethers.io/v5/getting-started/ isntead

Comment: @TheRef I used the command " npm install @openzeppelin/test-environment "  to install the test environment